# Two csproj DLLs, one NuGet package. How to do this?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I'm working on a project in Visual Studio that is split up into three different projects:

1. Acme.Webapplication
2. Acme.Domain
3. Acme.SDK

The `WebApplication` uses the `Domain` project where its entity classes are stored and some other "core" objects and interfaces.

The `SDK` project is something we give to 3rd party users. It makes API calls to our `WebApplication` project. The `SDK` project also makes use of the `Acme.Domain` project.

Now here comes the problem.

We create a NuGet package for our `Acme.SDK`. But because the `Acme.SDK` also uses the `Acme.Domain` project, so we also need to package that as a NuGet package.

What I'd like to have is just one NuGet package and still be able to reference both the classes from `Acme.SDK` and `Acme.Domain` from that one NuGet package instead of two loose NuGet packages.

Is this possible? And of so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. As you know, NuGet can create a package directly from a .csproj file. This is is basically the "automatic" mode. It's simple, but also has limitations.

You can also create a .nuspec file that allows you the explicitly state how you want to build your package. This can include multiple assemblies, dependencies, target different frameworks, etc.

First create a folder named *nuspec* in the root of your solution.

Open a command line in the *nuspec* folder.

Type: `nuget spec MyPackage`  <= use whatever your package id should be

This will create a *MyPackage.nuspec* file. Edit this file. You'll see a bunch of boilerplate code there. Update the values appropriately.

> NOTE: Once you start using an explicit .nuspec file, you will have to maintain these values (like Version number) as they will no longer pull from the .csproj file.

The main part you need to add is a `<files/>` section. Also make sure that you include the dependencies needed by BOTH your projects.

Here is a sample .nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Author Names</authors>
    <owners>Owner Names</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>MyPackage description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial version.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>

<!-- add dependencies here  
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="SomePackage.Id" />
    </dependencies>
-->

  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\ProjectA\bin\Debug\ProjectA.dll" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="..\ProjectB\bin\Debug\ProjectB.dll" target="lib\net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Notice how the files section references the actual assemblies you want to include in your package.

Once you've edited the .nuspec file, you need to create the package.

From the command line, type: `nuget pack MyPackage.nuspec`

It should then create a *MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg* file ready for upload to NuGet.org.

Here is the documentation for the Nuspec format: http://docs.nuget.org/Create/Nuspec-Reference